# Sharing Thunderbird profiles Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: thunderbird, sharing, migration

I want to have TB use the same set of messages, folders, calendar from both ubuntu 14.04 and W7. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92053/can-i-use-the-same-thunderbird-profile-under-windows-and-ubuntu) thread seems to answer my question, but it pertains to ubuntu 11.10. My reputation isn't sufficient to add to that discussion.

I don't like to assume that what worked for 11 (or 10 or older) will work with a new version of ubuntu -- is that overly cautious?

I have everything backed up, but what risks are there editing the profiles.ini?

Comment: I think those instructions will still work fine. Win7 uses C:\users\... but, usually still accepts Documents and Settings as an alias. It's not necessarily a great idea to constantly mount your Win partition, but the odds of something going wrong are low. Run chkdsk -f in Win now and then and never use hibernation in Win.

Comment: Thanks, @chaskes.  The "duplicate" didn't mention mounting or hibernation risks.